# Qt-Right click mouseReleaseEvents aren't caught by eventfilter,other events though are caught

Tags: qt, button, mouse

My application consists of a WebView widget. A mouse click on the widget is not handled by the mousePressEvent() of my application, but by the WebView widget. So, I installed an event filter to receive the events. Now, I get notified of all events, except the mouseReleaseEvent for the right click (Everything works fine for left clicks and mousePressEvent for the right click is also getting registered). I guess it has got something to do with context events getting generated by right clicks (a pop-up menu gets generated). But since I am using a filter, the event should first be sent to me. The following is the code for the event filter
in Jambi, but I hope I can modify an answer given in Qt for Jambi.

```
public boolean eventFilter(QObject o,QEvent event)
 {
  if (event.type()==QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress)   // One can call the mousePressEvent() functions from here,which can do this work but speed
  {
   if (((QMouseEvent)event).button()==Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)
   {
    mousebuttontype=1;
    clickedorpressed=1;
   }
   else
   if (((QMouseEvent)event).button()==Qt.MouseButton.RightButton)
   {
    mousebuttontype=2;
    System.out.println("right");
   }
   t1=QTime.currentTime();
   t1.start();
  }
  else
  if (event.type()==QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease)
  {
   if (t1.elapsed()>900)
   {
    switch(mousebuttontype)
    {
     case 1: browser.back();
      break;
     case 2: browser.forward();
      break;
    } 
   }System.out.println("choda");
  } 

  return false;
 }
```

MY BASIC AIM IS GETTING THE TIME INTERVAL FOR WHICH THE RIGHT CLICK WAS PRESSED. ANY WORKAROUND ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some digging around certainly seems to suggest that there may be no right-mouse release event being generated if that is the trigger for a context menu on your particular system. These are conveyed as a [QContextMenuEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcontextmenuevent.html).

This Qt Labs post [hints about this too](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation/).

A work around may be tricky if it is system dependent. Have you tried overriding event() in the QApplication class to see if the event comes through there? Some events don't necessarily get to the children but everything goes through QApplication::event().

Comment: Thanks. I subclassed QWebView and overrode the contextMenuEvent() slot to ignore context menu events. I handled the context menus in my application itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you is, subclass Qwebview and override mouseReleaseEvent event

Comment: Thanks. I did just that. I subclassed QWebView and overrode the contextMenuEvent() slot to ignore context menu events. I handled the context menus in my application itself.

Comment: Nice, if you feel the answer is valuable mark as right so it may help to other who are in sick of this problem..

Answer (score 1):

I've found a fix for this that I dont think will be system dependent.

My particular case was using mouseReleaseEvent in order to catch the events, and use them myself. I didn't get these events.

On all child widgets of the widget that I want to handle the event, I added to the class definition:

```
protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {event->ignore();}
```

This overrides the default implementation for context menu's, and sends the mouseReleaseEvent back up the parent chain like it would for other mousebuttons.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#ignore

This shows that it will probably propagate to the parent widget. As the link indicates, this fixed it for me at Qt 5.9, but I think it should work for virtually all version.

(I am aware this question is literally 7 years old, but it doesn't contain the fix that I think would be the best fix, and shows up as result 2 on google(qt not getting mouse release event on rightclick). So I think it deserves an up to date answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Without going in to broader implementation explanations, the core problem I needed to solve related to this issue was that I needed to know if a context menu swallowed the right-click so I could ensure some custom state was handled properly. The simplest workaround I was able to find was to implement [contextMenuEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent), which gets called after [mousePressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent), to detect if the event was accepted (a context menu was opened somewhere in my QGraphicsScene/Items). Here is a minimal example in Python to demonstrate how the event state might be used:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    event.setAccepted(False)
    super(MyGraphicsView, self).contextMenuEvent(event)        
    self.__context_menu_used = event.isAccepted()
```

Note you can also skip running the the base class [contextMenuEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent)  entirely to block the scene/items from opening a context menu. This is handy if you want to do 3D-DCC-like alt-RMB-zooming without accidentally opening a context menu, e.g.:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    # Block context menus if alt is held down
    if event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.AltModifier:
        return

    event.setAccepted(False)
    super(MyGraphicsView, self).contextMenuEvent(event)        
    self.__context_menu_used = event.isAccepted()
```